# LibQt4-core has unmet dependencies

Tags: qt, installation, qt4, apt

I'm trying to install libqt4-core, but it seems that for the dependencies, I have more recent versions than are compatible with this package. When I use `sudo apt-get install libqt4-core` my output is as follows:

```
user@computer:~/torch$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-core : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-test (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried doing `sudo apt-get install libqt4-core=4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1` instead in the hopes that this would be compatible with the packages I have installed already, but apt said it didn't find this version.

How can I get this installed?

Comment: I also tried uninstalling the dependencies and re-installing them with the older versions, but the dependencies in turn have more dependencies which conflict because they have the newer version number too. I don't think following this all the way down is a good idea, so I stopped. If there was an option to force everything to downgrade to debian version 2ubuntu4 instead of 2ubuntu4.1 that seems like that should fix this.

Comment: Have you disabled any repositories to download from?  If this is the case have them enabled and then try again.